# If $\{ a_{2n}\} \rightarrow L$ and $\{a_{2n+1}\} \rightarrow L$ show $\{a_n\} \rightarrow L$

Tags: real-analysis

Let $\{a_n\}$ be a sequence such that $\{ a_{2n}\} \rightarrow L$ and $\{a_{2n+1}\}  \rightarrow L$ show $\{a_n\} \rightarrow L$

my attempt so far

$\forall  \epsilon > 0 \exists n_1(\epsilon)$ s.t. $ \forall n > n_1(\epsilon)  \forall k $,

$|a_{2k+1} - L| <  \epsilon$

Also, $ \exists n_2(\epsilon)$ s.t. $\forall n > n_2(\epsilon), \forall k$

$|a_{2k} -  L | <  \epsilon$

Then

$|a_n - L | = | a_n + a_{2k} - a_{2k} - L | $

Comment: Good start, except what's $\forall n$ doing there. But after the introduction of $n_1(\epsilon)$  and $n_2(\epsilon)$, no further progress is made.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$a_{2k}\to L$ means that $\exists k'$ such that $|a_{2k}-L|<\varepsilon\forall k>k'$

$a_{2k+1}\to L$ means that $\exists k''$ such that $|a_{2k+1}-L|<\varepsilon\forall k>k''$.

Let $n_0=\max\{2k',2k''+1\}$.

For, $n>n_0$

Then $|a_n-L|$ is either $|a_{2k}-L|$ or $|a_{2k+1}-L|$ with $k>k'$ and $k>k''$.

Thus, $|a_n-L|<\varepsilon\forall n>n_0$

Answer (score 2):

There exists $K_1,K_2 \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $k > K_1 \implies |a_{2k} - L|< \epsilon$ and $k > K_2 \implies |a_{2k+1} - L|< \epsilon.$

If $n > 2\max(K_1,K_2)+1$ then either $n = 2k$ or $n = 2k+1$ with $k > \max(K_1,K_2)$ and ...